# Modifying PowerShell $using scope variables in thread started with Start-ThreadJob

Tags: multithreading, powershell, scope, powershell-core, powershell-jobs

If I understand the [PowerShell Scopes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier), it should be possible to assign to `$using` scope variables from threads started using `Start-ThreadJob`. The documentation says (**emphasis** mine):

> The `Using` scope modifier is supported in the following contexts:
>
> - ...
> - **Thread jobs**, started via `Start-ThreadJob` or `ForEach-Object -Parallel` (separate **thread session**)
>
> Depending on the context, embedded variable values are either independent copies of the data in the caller's scope or **references to it**.
> ...
> **In thread sessions, they are passed by reference. This means it is possible to modify call scope variables in a different thread.** To safely modify variables requires thread synchronization.

Yet the following fails to run:

```
$foo = 1

Start-ThreadJob {
    Write-Host $using:foo
    $using:foo = 2
} | Wait-Job | Out-Null

Write-Host $foo
```

It errors on `$using:foo = 2` with:

> The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.

Printing the variable with `Write-Host $using:foo` works correctly.

I'm using PowerShell 7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overwrite the `$using:` variable reference - but you can use it to dereference a variable value in the calling scope, at which point you can then mutate it (assuming a reference-type value was assigned to the original variable):

```
$foo = @{ 
  Value = 1
}
Start-ThreadJob {
    Write-Host $using:foo
    $foo = $using:foo
    $foo.Value = 2
} | Wait-Job | Out-Null

Write-Host $foo.Value
```

To ensure thread synchronization, I'd recommended a synchronized hashtable as your container type:

```
$foo = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{ 
  Value = 1
})

1..4 |%{Start-ThreadJob {
    Write-Host $using:foo
    $foo = $using:foo
    $foo.Value++
}} | Wait-Job | Out-Null

Write-Host $foo.Value
```

At which point you should see the (4-times incremented) value of `5`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know that. So do you think that my understanding of what the documentation means by *"passed by reference"* and *"possible to modify ... variables"* is wrong? Because this is not what I imagine by *"pass by reference"*. That's more like passing a pointer *by value*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'd certainly say that the documentation does not do a very good job of succinctly explaining "pass-by-reference probably means something else to you if you're coming from C#/VB.NET". I'm unsure how I'd personally phrase it, but I encourage you to [submit feedback on the PowerShell-Docs repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues)

Comment: I've submitted a feedback as you have suggested: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/7378

Comment: Btw, this syntax also works: `($using:foo).Value = 2`